# lines() not adding plot to plot(type='l')

Tags: r, plot, lines

I have this very super simple code, I give all the details for full reproducibility:

```
array=read.table('array.txt')[[1]]
vector=read.table('vector.txt')[[1]]
plot(1:5,vector,type = 'l')
lines(1:5,array)
```

Where `array.txt` is

```
4.11
0.004
0.004
0.003
0.003
```

and `vector.txt` is

```
23.047
7.242
6.85
7.018
6.648
```

The output contains only the first graph! WHY? Is it a bug of R?

Comment: Your ranges for your two sets of data are very different. Base R does not re-draw axes after the first `plot()`. You need to specify the y-range in such a case. Try `plot(1:5,vector,type = 'l', ylim=c(0, 25))`

Comment: you have to set range manually.

Comment: @MrFlick since I plot vector first, shouldn't I see at least the c(1,4.11) point in the vector graph? Of course plotting array first makes vector out of range, but why even the opposite?

Comment: @Nisba Nope. Look at the y-axis on the plot you get. It starts around 5. R has no idea lower values are coming later.